# addEventListener in JS not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, menu, addeventlistener, submenu

Firstly skim codes please.

index.html is :

```
<html><head><title>Home</title><script src="js/script.js"></script></head>
<body onLoad="init()">

<ul class="sup" id="sup">

    <li class="supitem">
        <a href="#" class="supcont">Home<div class="v"></div></a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li class="subitem"><a href="#" class="subcont">Home1</a></li>
            <li class="subitem"><a href="#" class="subcont">Home2</a></li>
            <li class="subitem"><a href="#" class="subcont">Home3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="supitem">
        <a href="#" class="supcont">Blog<div class="v"></div></a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li class="subitem"><a href="#" class="subcont">Blog1</a></li>
            <li class="subitem"><a href="#" class="subcont">Blog2</a></li>
            <li class="subitem"><a href="#" class="subcont">Blog3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js is :

```
function init() {
    var sky = 0;
    var sup         = document.getElementById("sup");
    var supitems    = sup.getElementsByClassName("supitem");

    for (var i = 0, ln = supitems.length; i < ln; i++) {
        var supconts = supitems[i].getElementsByClassName("supcont");
        var subs = supitems[i].getElementsByClassName("sub");
        var supcont = supconts[0];

        supcont.innerHTML = "SuperMenu"+i;

        if (subs.length > 0) {
            var sub         = subs[0];

            supcont.addEventListener("click",function() {
                toggleVisibility(sub); });

            supcont.style.background = "#"+sky+sky+sky;
            sub.style.background = "#"+sky+sky+sky;
            sky += 4;
        }
    }
}

function toggleVisibility(object) {
    object.style.visibility =
        (object.style.visibility == "hidden" ?"visible" :"hidden");
}
```

What I would like to do is when I press supermenu all sub-menus' visibility to be toggled. But I don't know where I have made a mistake. When I press Supmenu0, submenus of Supmenu1 are toggled, not submenus of Supmenu1. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I think the problem is in addEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question but I will try to give a better explanation than I have found.  When you pass a function as a parameter (as when defining your event handler), javascript does not evaluate the function at that time, but instead stores the function along with a reference to its parent `scope`.

The function does not get evaluated until the event handler is triggered. At that time, the interpreter will check the value of `sub` in the parent `scope`. Since this will always happen after your `for` loop has completed, it will always find the last value of `sub`, i.e. whatever `sub` was when your `for` loop was completed. So all of your event listeners will use the last value of `sub`.

We can get the desired behavior by creating a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FClosures).  Replace this:

```
supcont.addEventListener("click",function() {
    toggleVisibility(sub); });
```

with this:

```
(function(localSub) {
    supcont.addEventListener("click",function() {
        toggleVisibility(localSub);
    });    
})(sub);
```

The reason this works is because we wrap each event handler declaration with a new parent `scope` by invoking an IIFE.  This forces the event handler to retain a copy of the `scope` inside the IIFE (called creating a closure over that `scope`).  Now, when the event handler goes looking for `localSub`, it will find it in the new parent `scope` and it will have the value we want.

Comment: Thanks sir. BTW I just learned what is closure. Leaving link here it just in case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work :)